# Rails model attribute allow nil but validate when not

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to validate an input box value in two cases:

1. If nil? then save successfully, no errors
2. If not nil? then validate its format

I have a simple line here:

```
validates :ip_addr, format: { with: Regexp.union(Resolv::IPv4::Regex)}
```

This will work in all cases but won't allow a nil/empty value as it throws an exception. But:

```
validates :ip_addr, format: { with: Regexp.union(Resolv::IPv4::Regex)}, allow_nil: true
```

and

```
validates :ip_addr, format: { with: Regexp.union(Resolv::IPv4::Regex)}, allow_blank: true
```

Will allow nil/empty values but If the input is invalid e.g. "33@@@#$" then it returns "true".

How could I include both cases ? Is that possible ?

EDIT: It seems that `Regexp.union(Resolv::IPv4::Regex).match("something")` returns nil so If the validation works the same way, it will return nil in wrong values and `allow_nil: true` will allow them to be persisted like this.

Comment: Did you check the [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#allow-nil)?

Comment: @j-dexx of course. But my problem is the opposite. If not nil, it doesn't validate.

Comment: why don't you just use a conditional: `unless ip_addr.nil?`

Comment: Is that because of an issue in rails?  Or that the regex isn't correct?

Comment: @j-dexx I have no idea. This is a strange behaviour and in order to work directly with the model I am testing in rails console with update/update!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typecasting seems to be the problem.

The solution below works fine:

```
validates :ip_addr, format: { with: Resolv::IPv4::Regex }, 
    presence: false, unless: Proc.new { |ifc| ifc.ip_addr_before_type_cast.blank? }
```

Most probably we need to check If the variable's value is blank before casting it to inet (postgreSQL).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
validates :ip_addr, format: { with: Regexp.union(Resolv::IPv4::Regex)}, if: :ip_addr
```

I am not sure whether the above one will work. If it doesn't, do this

```
validate :ip_addr_format_check, if: :ip_addr

def ip_addr_format_check
  unless ip_addr =~ Regexp.union(Resolv::IPv4::Regex)
    errors.add(:base, "Error you want to show")
  end
end
```

Comment: I actually used this for a condition in my app. I don't know why it doesn't work. This is the solution I know. Sorry it wasn't any help